# Seg Fault when counting shifts in insertion sort - C

Tags: c, count, segmentation-fault, insertion-sort

I wrote the following to sort N integers read in from stdin in C, sort them using insertion-sort, and count the number of swaps that were needed to sort it for a SPOJ problem: http://www.spoj.com/problems/CODESPTB/

My code works for the sample inputs given and I've also tested with larger integer sets f larger values and everything seems to work fine. However, when I run it on SPOJ's online judge it fails with a Segmentation Fault at runtime. Unforunately, the creator of the problem on SPOJ has not made reviewing failures an option. I have no clue what's causing the seg fault. Does anything in my code jump out at you as to what might be causing it?

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_BUFF 100

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char buffer[MAX_BUFF];
    char *long_str;
    int T, N;
    long *a;

    printf("Enter a T value between 1 and 5 inclusive: ");
    bzero(buffer, MAX_BUFF);
    fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFF - 1, stdin);
    T = atoi(buffer);
    if(T<1 || T>5){
        printf("Error: T must be 1<=T<=5\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    const char delim[2] = " ";
    char *token;

    while(T > 0){
        printf("Enter a N value between 1 and 100000 inclusive: ");
        bzero(buffer,MAX_BUFF);
        fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFF-1, stdin);
        N = atoi(buffer);
        if(N<1 || N>100000){
            printf("Error: N must be 1<=N<=100000\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        int current_size = 0;
        long_str = malloc(MAX_BUFF);
        current_size = MAX_BUFF;
        printf("Enter N integers separated by spaces: ");
        if(long_str != NULL){
            int c = EOF;
            unsigned int i = 0;
            while(( c = getchar() ) != '\n' && c != EOF){
                long_str[i++]=(char)c;
                if(i==current_size){
                    current_size = i + MAX_BUFF;
                    long_str = realloc(long_str, current_size);
                }
            }
            long_str[i] = '\0';

        }
        token = strtok(long_str, delim);
        a[0]=atol(token);
        int i = 1;
        while (token != NULL && i < N) {
            token = strtok(NULL, delim);
            if(token == NULL){
                printf("Error, not enough ints specified, terminating\n");
                exit(0);
            }
            a[i] = atol(token);
            i++;
        }
        free(long_str);

        int j, tmp, count;
        count = 0;
        for(i=1; i<N; i++){
            j=i;
            while(j>0 && a[j]<a[j-1]){
                tmp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j-1];
                a[j-1] =  tmp;
                j--;
                count++;
            } 
        }
    T--;
    }
}
```

Comment: As a new user to stack overflow, if you're going to downvote my question could you at least explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never allocate space for `a`:

```
long *a;
...
    a[0]=atol(token);
    ...
        a[i] = atol(token);
```

Unfortunately, one possibility of undefined behaviour is that it "seems to work fine".

Comment: Thank you for the response. I entirely refactored my code using scanf instead of fgets and it seems to be working now. Is my best bet to delete this post or what should I do with it?